# Detecting closest collectionviewcell to the center of the collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Suspect I am doing something fundamentally wrong below... I have a horizontal collectionview and after dragging I want to snap the closest cell to the center.  But my results are unpredictable... what am I doing wrong here?

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    // Find collectionview cell nearest to the center of collectionView
    // Arbitrarily start with the last cell (as a default)
    var closestCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.visibleCells()[0];
    for cell in collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {
        let closestCellDelta = abs(closestCell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0)
        let cellDelta = abs(cell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0)
        if (cellDelta < closestCellDelta){
            closestCell = cell
        }
    }
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(closestCell)
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out my original code was missing accounting for the collecitonview content offset. In addition, I've moved the centering into the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating callback. I've modified the original code and included it below.

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Find collectionview cell nearest to the center of collectionView
    // Arbitrarily start with the last cell (as a default)
    var closestCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.visibleCells()[0];
    for cell in collectionView!.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell] {
        let closestCellDelta = abs(closestCell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0 - collectionView.contentOffset.x)
        let cellDelta = abs(cell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0 - collectionView.contentOffset.x)
        if (cellDelta < closestCellDelta){
            closestCell = cell
        }
    }
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(closestCell)
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: and you nailed itt... ;)

Comment: Close but not a fix for me.  The cell at position 1 is always skipped in favor of cells 0 or 2.  That's in portrait.  In landscape, the next to last cell is similarly affected.

Comment: worked a charm, had to update the inset for section to allow centering the first & last items though

Comment: objective c version please.

Comment: I've seen several examples of this in my searches, and every time the answer is the scrollViewDidSomething function with reference to "collectionView" inside. I get "ambiguous use of collectionView" whenever I try this. Where do you define "collectionView"? Is the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating function inside another function that allows you to reference collectionView?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:self.collectionView.center];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
```

SWIFT:

```
let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(self.collectionView.center)
self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: Seems like this should work, but for me indexPathForItemAtPoint is returning nil.

Comment: returns nil always? or only at certain times?

Comment: always... which is interesting, maybe something else going on. When I get the chance I will post more complete code.

Comment: the suggested solution here does return nil when the point falls between cells, so it is not a working solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions reliably worked for me, so I wrote this and it works 100% of the time. Very simple. Even the built in indexPathForItemAtPoint was not working 100%.

```
extension UICollectionView {
    
    var centerMostCell:UICollectionViewCell? {
        guard let superview = superview else { return nil }
        let centerInWindow = superview.convert(center, to: nil)
        guard visibleCells.count > 0 else { return nil }
        var closestCell:UICollectionViewCell?
        for cell in visibleCells {
            guard let sv = cell.superview else { continue }
            let cellFrameInWindow = sv.convert(cell.frame, to: nil)
            if cellFrameInWindow.contains(centerInWindow) {
                closestCell = cell
                break
            }
        }
        return closestCell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: After posting the answer I realized that if there is no cell containing the center point of the collection view this will return nil. So, as long as there is a cell containing the center then you will get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version for Swift 4

```
var closestCell = collectionView.visibleCells[0]
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
    let closestCellDelta = abs(closestCell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0 - collectionView.contentOffset.x)
    let cellDelta = abs(cell.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0 - collectionView.contentOffset.x)
    if (cellDelta < closestCellDelta){
        closestCell = cell
    }
}

let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: closestCell)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath!, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

- When stop dragging, just pick the center and use it to choose the indexpath

> swift 4.2

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let indexPath = photoCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: photoCollectionView.center)
    photoCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var centerUICollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell? {
  get {
    // 1 
    guard let center = collectionView.superview?.convert(collectionView.center, to: collectionView) else { return nil }

    // 2  
    guard let centerIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: center) else { return nil }

    // 3
    return collectionView.cellForItem(at: centerIndexPath)
  }
}
```

1: Need to make sure we are *converting the point from superview coordinate space to collectionView's space*

2: Use the collectionView's local space point to find the indexPath

3: Return the cell for indexPath

Answer (score 0):

```
 public func closestIndexPathToCenter() -> IndexPath? {
    guard let cv = collectionView else { return nil }
   
    let visibleCenterPositionOfScrollView = Float(cv.contentOffset.x + (cv.bounds.size.width / 2))
        var closestCellIndex = -1
        var closestDistance: Float = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        for i in 0..<cv.visibleCells.count {
            let cell = cv.visibleCells[i]
            let cellWidth = cell.bounds.size.width
            let cellCenter = Float(cell.frame.origin.x + cellWidth / 2)

            // Now calculate closest cell
            let distance: Float = fabsf(visibleCenterPositionOfScrollView - cellCenter)
            if distance < closestDistance {
                closestDistance = distance
                closestCellIndex = cv.indexPath(for: cell)!.row
            }
        }
        if closestCellIndex != -1 {
            return IndexPath(row: closestCellIndex, section: 0)
        }else {
            return nil
        }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).