# Access collectionView from scrollViewDidEndDecelerating

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a UICollectionView called dayPicker that scrolls horizontally, and lets you select the day of the month. When the user stops scrolling (scrollViewDidEndDecelerating), I want the app to do something with that day, accessible from the cell's label. All of the answers I have seen online are similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178797/9036092

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    var someCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.visibleCells()[0];
    
    // Other code follows...
}
```

When I try to access `collectionView` from inside the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` function, I get a `Ambiguous use of collectionView` error. When I substitute the actual name of my UICollectionView (dayPicker), it errors out with "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".

My question is: how do you get to `collectionView` from inside the `scrollViewDidSomething` function? Currently my `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` function is inside a `UICollectionViewDelegate` in my view controller, and I have also tried putting it in a `UIScrollViewDelegate` extension.

Current code:

```
extension PageOneViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: scrollView.frame.midY)
        print(centerPoint) // Successfully prints the same center point every time scrolling stops
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: centerPoint) // Ambiguous error
        let indexPath = dayPicker.indexPathForItem(at: centerPoint) // Fatal error
    }
}
```

Screenshot of scrollable UICollectionView in question:

[image]

I also have another method of when the user taps on the day, and it is working flawlessly. Trying to complete the experience with the scrolling ending.

Xcode 11.4.1/Swift 5

Comment: have you tried `self.collectionView`? Otherwise may recommend maintaining a strong reference to the `collectionView` by way of a variable in your extension which you set

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access objects that are out-of-scope... use breakpoints to step through your code and evaluate the variables. If you don't find the error that way, try to put together a [mre] to get more help.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli great suggestion, I did try that with no success unfortunately. I also tried defining it in the extension, but Xcode told me I couldn't define a variable in an extension? Figured out another way, see answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, for those who come across this thread looking for the same answer. Big thanks to this answer here for a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385718/9036092

The missing ingredient was to cast `scrollView` as a `UICollectionView` so that you can access the collectionView's cell properties.

Working code:

```
extension PageOneViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let collectionView = scrollView as! UICollectionView // This is crucial
        
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: scrollView.frame.midY)
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: centerPoint)
        let centerCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath!) as! MyCustomCell
        let selectedDay = centerCell.dayLabel.text //
        print(selectedDay) // Prints the value of the day in the center of the collectionView, as a string
    }
}
```